# Vivado doesn't acknowledge changes of testbench file

Tags: vhdl, vivado

I need some help with Vivado 2015.4. VHDL

I have added a testbench file to my project and it had some errors in it. After I amended these errors but when I re-run the simulation it is not not working because of the same errors that were there before.

So the changes weren't acknowledged. For some reason that I am missing.

I saved the file I also tried to change the compile order by move it up in the hierarchy but no change. What am I missing here? There must be setting there that I have not set because even restarting Vivado doesn't help.

Answer (score 2):

I encountered a similar problem and found a solution that worked for me at least:

Right clicking "Run Simulation", "Simulation Settings...", then navigating to the "Advanced" tab gives you an option "Enable incremental compilation".

To quote the option, this box "Enables incremental compilation and preserves simulation files during successive simulation runs".  Unchecking it made my problem go away, I have no idea why it is the default setting.

Answer (score 1):

When you added the file to your project, by default it is set to copy the file into a location within a 'ProjectName.sim' folder, within your project folder. Could this have happened, and you are now not editing this copied file that Vivado is using?

The easy way to find the file Vivado is actually using, is to double click that file in the project hierarchy.

Comment: Yeah thats right but even if I double clock on the file it is shown in the editor window updated. So I don't understand why vivado doesn't see that. But I think you are on to something there

Comment: @AI maybe you could try looking in the .sims folder for your test bench and opening it with another editor

Comment: I did open the tb.vhd file that I am using somewhere in the project dir. It is updated with all the changes. In the .sim folder however is no vhd file. There is compile.bat though. How do I make it run in vivado before I start sim?

Comment: @AI if you've proven that the file you're editing is the one it's using, then my answer is not the solution. I guess you'll have to wait for another idea from someone else; I don't use the Vivado simulator myself, sorry.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know why it isn't working.

But one solution is to delete it from the Manager and add it again manually.

Then run simulation and it will compile the latest version and run the simulation if it hasn't any error in it.